# How to detect mouse placement in java

Tags: java, mouseevent, mousemove

I have been having issues with using the `MouseInfo` class in Java Applets.

```
int somex = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x;         
int somey = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y;`
```

The above code works just fine when in a normal java program, but in an applet, I get a

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.awt.AWTPermission watchMousePointer)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:374)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at java.awt.MouseInfo.getPointerInfo(MouseInfo.java:62)
    at Mousefollow.getCOOR(Mousefollow.java:208)
    at Mousefollow.paint(Mousefollow.java:160)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:713)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:693)
    etc etc etc.
```

Does anyone know why I cannot use that code in an applet? 
How do I change the security manager so this will work?

The reason that I ask this is that I have a large applet (game) which works great, except for the fact that I need to add in the mouse controls.

If anyone has a suggestion on how to adapt the above code, or an entirely different way to find the position of the mouse/keyboard, it would be appreciated.

It works relatively by using `KeyListener`, `MouseListener`, `MouseMotionListener`, `ActionListener` and such, but the problem with `MouseMotion` is that if the mouse is held still, it cannot detect the position of the mouse.

Comment: I don't see how using MouseListener or MouseAdapter could help me find the location of the mouse if no action had taken place.

Comment: Please ignore my suggestion. Sorry.

Comment: @user1618517 consider [signing](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) your applet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applets are not normal applications. See the doc [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html) on the Java Tutorial. I would suggest you track the mouse cursor in your game with a `MouseMotionListener`.

Just save the last known position in a variable so you can detect the position when the user is not moving the mouse.

If you want your applet to behave more like a proper application you will need to sign it: See [Security in Rich Internet Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/security.html)  on the Java Tutorial.